# set bootstrap non-responsive divs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've removed the *bootstrap-responsive.css* link from `<head>`, but my page is still responsive.
I have three `<div class"row">`, each having tree `<div class="span4">` to hold some data, everything looking like a 3x3 square. My resolution is 1600x872 and the "square" looks perfect, but when I resize my browser window, the divs go crazy, looking like a rectangle. I just want the divs to hold their places, meaning when I resize the window, scroll bars show appear. Do you have a solution?

Comment: If you remove the `bootsrap-responsive.css` it's almost imposible that you keep the responsive design in your web. Can you put a `jsfiddle` to show your problem to us?

Comment: See my last answer. Belive it, the design is still responsive even with `bootstrap-responsive.css` out. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you wrapping the rows inside a `.container` div?

When you don't make use of the `.container`, then the `.span4` elements in the rows will give you a "rectangle" effect when you reduce the width of the screen.

You can test it out on this jsbin example. 
The top row is not wrapped inside a `.container`, but the bottom row is.

http://jsbin.com/okogis/1

http://jsbin.com/okogis/1/edit

```
       <!-- this row has no .container, and will 
look like a rectangle when you reduce screen width -->
       <h4>NO .container</h4>  
        <div class="row">
          <div class="span4">
            <div class="spacer200 a1"></div>
          </div>
            <div class="span4">
             <div class="spacer200 a2"></div>
          </div>
            <div class="span4">
              <div class="spacer200 a3"></div>
          </div>
        </div>  

          <div class="spacer50"></div> 

        <!-- this row does have a .container, 
             and will not give the rectangle effect -->
        <div class="container">
          <h4>.container wrapping the row</h4>  
          <div class="row">
            <div class="span4">
              <div class="spacer200 a1"></div>
            </div>
              <div class="span4">
               <div class="spacer200 a2"></div>
            </div>
              <div class="span4">
                <div class="spacer200 a3"></div>
            </div>
          </div> 
        </div>
```

Comment: Because I was unable to deal with the responsive design, I thought using an unresponsive one will be the answer, but later I've seen that only some of the divs where inside `.contaier`, not all, and this was the root of the view problem. Now everything is inside the container and responsive. Thank you for your help!